# Does $\pi_k(M)\neq 0$ implies $\operatorname{ind}(\gamma) < k$?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

Here is a line of proof of [Theorem 1.15](https://books.google.com/books?id=GoyDAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA8) from Ricci Flow and the Sphere Theorem
by Simon Brendle

> Let us fix two
> points $p, q \in M$ such that $d(p, q) = \operatorname{diam}(M, g) > 2$. **Since $\pi_k(M)\neq 0$, there
> exists a geodesic $\gamma : [0,1] \to M$ such that $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1) = p$ and $\operatorname{ind}(\gamma) < k$.**

**Q:** By which argument the author concluded that $\operatorname{ind}(\gamma) < k$? Is this a general fact that $\pi_k(M)\neq 0 \implies \operatorname{ind}(\gamma) < k$?

**Note:** $\operatorname{ind}(\gamma):=$ Morse index of $\gamma$.

Comment: has been posted on [mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/q/364825/90655)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been posted and  answered on MO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question had been asked on Mathoverflow and is [answered](https://mathoverflow.net/a/364826/41094). Below is the direct quote of the answer:

Very roughly speaking: Geodesics $\gamma:[0,1]\to M$ with $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)=p$ and $\operatorname{ind}(\gamma)<k$ correspond to critical points of Morse index less than $k$ of the energy functional $E:\Omega_p(M)\to \mathbb{R}$, where $\Omega_p(M)$ is the space of loops based at $p$.

The assumption that $\pi_k(M)\cong\pi_{k-1}(\Omega_p(M))\neq 0$ implies that $H_i(\Omega_p(M))\neq 0$ for some $i\leq k-1$, by the Hurewicz Theorem. Then Morse homology implies there must be a critical point of index less than $k$.